# Site inaccessible after upgrading from 3.8.3 to 3.8.7

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

The site auto update got to 100% but there was an error at the end.

Now I cannot access the backend or the frondend and only get this error.

Fatal error: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin' not found in /home/.sites/92/site2697155/web/plugins/system/sessiongc/sessiongc.php on line 23

Can someone help me to restore my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change session_handle in configuration.ftp to "none"

```
public $session_handler = 'none';
```

To do this, you can use FTP and modify configuration.php directly

But i guess your issue caused by 3rd plugin
Try to use FTP and rename folder

```
/home/.sites/92/site2697155/web/plugins/system/sessiongc
```

to

```
/home/.sites/92/site2697155/web/plugins/system/sessiongc.bak
```

And try to check your site.

Comment: It was indeed a plug in, I managed to get into the backend after manual updating and remove it, thx